# Why does part of styles didn't cached up, after moving them to the dedicated .css file?

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to make a prototype bootstrap based page with some custom elements.
While work was in process - I was putting all the custom styles and scripts directly into the index.html page (keeping in mind, that I will migrate this guys, after finish). Probably it was not the best idea, but still.
Anyway - everything was fine, except of one: an " text-decoration: none;", for a custom class didn't cached up. 
Here is the style:

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;            
z-index: 3;
position:absolute;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.3s;

}
.sidenav a {
left: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
position: absolute;
transition: 0.3s;            
}
```

if it is described into a .html page - all good. But when it is described into a .css file - the hyperlink is underlined, on mouse over.
Everything else cached up perfectly, .sidenav class and all the ".sidenav a" properties are reflected perfectly.

So my question is not how to fix it, but why is this happen?
Thank you in advance!

Update:
Here is what I am trying to implement [Offcanvas layout](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav)

Exactly the same thing, but if I take the styles out - the menu options get underscored on mouse over.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cached up".

Comment: Also, can you post an example that demonstrates the issue? I did a quick and dirty test, but nothing shows up, because .sidenav turns out to have a width of 0.

Comment: Sure, see updated question.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. Note that the code must be included in the post itself, not on a third-party website.

Comment: I am not able to compare your 2 versions, they don't seem to be anything like the other. But I'm going to make a guess as to what your problem is: in-file css has precedence over linked css. If you're linking multiple css stylesheets (like Bootstrap and your own, for example), precedence could be altered depending on the order in which you're linking the files and how specific your css is. If this is something you think might be happening, please post the link to the page where it is happening with the linked css stylesheets, and tell me what link is not getting the underline.

Comment: @vic3685 impressive, that was the thing. My custom style.css were linked before bootstrap.css. Thank you.

Comment: @EgorOsaulenko: I'm glad! I posted my comment as an answer, can you mark it as the correct one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess as to what your problem is: in-file css has precedence over linked css. If you're linking multiple css stylesheets (like Bootstrap and your own, for example), precedence could be altered depending on the order in which you're linking the files and how specific your css is.

If this is something you think might be happening, please post the link to the page where it is happening with the linked css stylesheets, and tell me what link is not getting the underline.

Comment: This is not completely true. In-file css has exactly the same precedence as linked css. _Only_ the order in which they appear influences things.